# error javascript, jquery with tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm on a project and when hidden objects and unconcealed brand me this error
columns does not respect me, all the objects above me
here I leave the demo so they can what I mention 
http://jsfiddle.net/FT9BJ/

and part of the HTML only lack the JavaScript code in the demo will be able to check
 code html

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table  width="70%" border="1">
                    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <label>Area Medica</label>
    </td>
        <td>
        <select id="estado" onchange="habilitarComboa1(this.value);">
        <option value="1">Seleccione 1 opcion</option>
        <option value="2">Laboratorio</option>
        <option value="3">Datos Generales</option>
        <option value="4">Enfermeria</option>
        <option value="5">Nutricion</option>
        <option value="6">Odontologia</option>
        <option value="7">Área médica</option>
        </select>
        </td>


        <td>
            <label  id="departamento1" >Resultado</label>
        </td>
    <td id="columna1" style="display:none">


        <select name="departamento" id="departamento" onchange="habilitarCombo1a1(this.value);" style="display:none" >
        <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
        <option value="BH-Eritrocitos"> BH-Eritrocitos  </option>
        <option value="BH-Hematócrito"> BH-Hematócrito  </option>
        <option value="BH-Hemoglobina"> BH-Hemoglobina  </option>
        <option value="BH-VCM"> BH-VCM  </option>
        <option value="BH-CMHbC">   BH-CMHbC    </option>
        <option value="BH-CMHb">    BH-CMHb </option>
        <option value="BH-Leucocitos">  BH-Leucocitos   </option>
        <option value="BH-Plaquetas">   BH-Plaquetas    </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-Linfocitos">    RD-Relativos-Linfocitos </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-Monocitos"> RD-Relativos-Monocitos  </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-Eosinófilos">   RD-Relativos-Eosinófilos    </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-Basófilos"> RD-Relativos-Basófilos  </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-NeuSegmentados">    RD-Relativos-NeuSegmentados </option>
        <option value="RD-Relativos-NeuBanda">  RD-Relativos-NeuBanda   </option>
        <option value="Grupo Sanguíneo">    Grupo Sanguíneo </option>
        <option value="Factor RH">  Factor RH   </option>
        <option value="Du"> Du  </option>
        <option value="QCGlucosa">  QC-Glucosa  </option>
        <option value="QC-Triglicéridos">   QC-Triglicéridos    </option>
        <option value="QC-Colésterol">  QC-Colésterol   </option>
        <option value="VDRL">   VDRL    </option>
        <option value="EGO-Densidad">   EGO-Densidad    </option>
        <option value="EGO-PH"> EGO-PH  </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Glucosa"> EGO-EQ-Glucosa  </option>
        <option value="Bilirubina"> EGO-EQ-Bilirubina</option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Urobilinógeno">   EGO-EQ-Urobilinógeno    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Nitritos">    EGO-EQ-Nitritos </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Proteínas">   EGO-EQ-Proteínas    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-CuerposCetónicos">    EGO-EQ-CuerposCetónicos </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Sangre">  EGO-EQ-Sangre   </option>
        <option value="EGO-EQ-Leucocitos">  EGO-EQ-Leucocitos   </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Leucocitos">  EGO-EM-Leucocitos   </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Bacterias">   EGO-EM-Bacterias    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Parasitos">   EGO-EM-Parasitos    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-CelEpiteliales">  EGO-EM-CelEpiteliales   </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Eritrocitos"> EGO-EM-Eritrocitos  </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Levaduras">   EGO-EM-Levaduras    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-FilamentoMucoso"> EGO-EM-FilamentoMucoso  </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Cristales">   EGO-EM-Cristales    </option>
        <option value="EGO-EM-Cilindros">   EGO-EM-Cilindros    </option>   
        </select>

            <select  id="areamed" style= "display:none" onchange="habilitarCombo021(this.value);">
            <option selected="" value="">[Seleccione una opcion]</option>
            <option value="4">peso</option>
            <option value="5">Talla</option>
            <option value="6">Pliegue Tricipial</option>
            <option value="7">Embarazada</option>
            <option value="8">Cintura</option>
            <option value="9">IMC</option>
            </select>

        <!-- odontologia -->
        <select  id="odontologia" style= "display:none" onchange="habilitarCombo021(this.value);">
       <option selected="" value="">[Seleccione una opcion]</option>
       <option value="10">veces cepilla dientes</option>
       <option value="11">Tecnica cepillado</option>
       <option value="12">Profilaxis aguda</option>
       <option value="13" >Gingivorragia espontanea</option>
       <option value="14">Gingivorragia mecánica</option>
       <option value="15">Ortodoncia actual</option>
       <option value="16">Ortodoncia anterior</option>
       <option value="17" >dolor terceros molares</option>
       <option value="18">Total CPO</option>
       <option value="19">Dientes con caries</option>
        </select>

    <!-- nutricion -->
    <select  id="nutricion" style= "display:none" onchange="habilitarCombo021(this.value);">
       <option value="">Selecciona una opcion</option>
       <option value="20">Fumar</option>
       <option value="21">Bebidas Alcoholicas</option>
       <option value="22">Adicción drogas</option>
       <option value="23">Vida sexual</option>
       <option value="24">Edad vida sexual</option>
       <option value="25">Anticoncepción </option>
       <option value="26">Protección (Preservativo) </option>
       <option value="27">Núm. Parejas sexuales</option>
        </select>
    </td>



    <td id="columna2" style="display:none">
        <!-- select para elementos tipo numerico -->
        <select name="articulo" id="articulo"  style="display:none">
        <option selected="" value="">selecione valor</option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value="=">=</option>
        </select>

        <!-- select para  grupo sanguineo -->
        <select name="sangre" id="sangre"  style="display:none">
        <option selected="" value="">selecione valor</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="AB">O</option>
        </select>
        <!-- select para  factor rh y vdrl -->
            <!-- area de enfermeria  -->
        <!-- select enfermeria  -->
        <select name="enfermeria" id="enfermeria" onchange="habilitarCombo5a1(this.value);" style="display:none" >
        <option value="">seleciona una opcion</option>
        <option value="1">Frecuencia cardiaca numerico</option>
        <option value="2">Temperatura axilar numerico</option>
        <option value="3">Frecuencia de respiración</option>
        <option value="4">Frecuencia de pulso numerico</option>
        </select>


            <select name="aream" id="aream" style="display:none" onchange="habilitarCombo4a1(this.value);" >
        <option value="">Selecciona una opcion</option>
        <option value="1">Sexo</option>
        <option value="2">Fecha de nacimiento</option>
        <option value="3">Discapacidad</option>
        <option value="4">Edad</option>
        <option value="5">Area</option>
        <option value="6">Codigo del programa</option>
        <option value="7">Descripcion del programa</option>
        </select>

    </td>

    <!-- area medica -->
    <td id="columna3" style="display:none">
    <select name="posinega" id="posinega"  style="display:none">
        <option selected="" value="">selecione valor</option>
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>

        </select>

        <select  id="mayme"  style="display:none">
        <option selected="" value="">selecione valor</option>
        <option value="1"> < </option>
        <option value="2"> > </option>
        <option value="3"> = </option>
        </select>
    <!-- etiqueta -->
        <label style="display:none">Area Medica</label>
    <!-- select  -->

        <!-- select boleano  -->
        <select name="sino" id="sino"style="display:none">
        <option value="1">Si </option>
        <option value="2">No</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td id="columna4" style="display:none">
    <input name="articulo2" id="articulo2" style="display:none"/>
        <!-- select sexo -->
        <select name="sexo" id="sexo"  style="display:none">
        <option value="1">Masculino </option>
        <option value="2">Femenino</option>
        </select>
        <!-- select areas  -->
        <select name="areas1" id="areas1"  style="display:none" >
        <option value="1">HUMANIDADES</option>
        <option value="2">AREA CIENCIAS BIOLOGICO AGROPECUARIAS</option>
        <option value="3">AREA TECNICA  </option>
        <option value="4">AREA ECONOMICO ADMINISTRATIVA </option>
        <option value="5">AREA CIENCIAS DE LA SALUD </option>
        </select>




    </td>

    <!-- numerico para la funcion de enfermeria -->



    <td id="columna5" style="display:none">




        <select  id="si"  style="display:none">
        <option label= "Yes" value= "yes"> Sí </option>
        <option selected= "selected" label= "No" value= "no"> No </option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <!-- boton de la funcion agregar -->
        <td><input type="button" value="+" class="clsAgregarFila"></td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jss/manipulacion.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: There are many `getElementById`s in your code, why don't you use classes?

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to the page if it's not there and redefine `habilitarComboa1`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof jQuery === undefined){
    var src = document.createElement('script'); src.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(src);
}

$(function(){
    // hide all of the options initially
    $('.options').hide();
})

var habilitarComboa1 = function(dato){
    var $option = $('#'+dato).show();
    $('.options').not($option).hide();
}
</script>
```

Change the value of the option to the id of the linked select list

```
<select id="estado" onchange="habilitarComboa1(this.value);">
    <option value="departmento">Laboratorio</option>
</select>
```

Add the class "options" to your hidden select lists

```
<select name="departamento" id="departamento" class="options" onchange="habilitarCombo1a1(this.value);" style="display:none" >
    <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
</select>
```